# Aurelia-i18n + Typescript 2.3.0 Setup

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia

I am trying to use aurelia-i18n in my project where i use Typescript 2.3 and webpack (no aurelia-cli).
I have installed so far the following:

```
npm install aurelia-i18n i18next i18next-resource-store-loader i18next-xhr-backend @types/i18next @types/i18next-xhr-backend --save
```

In my main.ts my code looks like this:

```
import {I18N, TCustomAttribute} from 'aurelia-i18n';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import resBundle from 'i18next-resource-store-loader!./assets/i18n/index.js';

export async function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
        let aliases = ['t', 'i18n'];
        let cl = new ConfigLocales;
        TCustomAttribute.configureAliases(aliases);
        instance.i18next.use(Backend); 

        return instance.setup({
            fallbackLng: 'en', 
            whitelist: ['en', 'es'],
            preload: ['en', 'es'], 
            ns: 'translation',
            attributes: aliases, 
            lng: 'en', 
            debug: true, 
            resources: resBundle
        });
    })
    .plugin('aurelia-dialog', config => {
      config.useDefaults();
    })
    .developmentLogging();

  await aurelia.start();
  aurelia.setRoot('app');
}
```

When I am doing npm start I get the following errors:

1. TypeError: "_aureliaPal.PLATFORM.moduleName is not a function".
2. error TS2307: Cannot find module
   'i18next-resource-store-loader!./assets/i18n/index.js'.

My file system where I have put the lang files looks like this:

```
src/
    -assets/
    -i18n/
            -index.js
            -en/
                -translation.json
            -es/
                -translation.json
    -main.ts
```

I have managed in the past to make it work in an aurelia project without typescript but now I keep getting errors.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, Before you start using "aurelia-i18n", You need to "npm install" it with "i18next". Once both are installed, you need to load them into your "main.ts" by using another loader helper "PLATFORM" as below ..


  import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-i18n'), (instance: I18N) =>

After you execute these code-lines, you can use "aurelia-i18n" in your code files.